# When foc jars included in eclipse, the icons disapeared

Tags: java, vaadin

I am using [focframework](https://github.com/FOC-framework/framework) to develop a full stack business web application.

In Eclipse I was including focframework jars in maven dependency without loading the focframework as projects in eclise. All Icons were appearing normally.

After I included the foc source projects in eclipse workspace, this made some icons disappear. Like the ADD, DELETE, OPEN... icons. The [FontAwesome](https://fontawesome.com/) icons still appear normally.

Did I miss something?

Comment: Please elaborate your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some icons are in focVaadinTheme. When foc is included using maven the jar is searched and icons are loaded fine. Since you are using the project in eclipse directly, then in your web server (tomcat or other) runtime in eclipse you need to include the folder focVaadinTheme not only the project.

In Eclipse go to your server run configuration and follow the numbered steps bellow:

[image: Click this link to see the Eclipse server run config]